# WebStorm ест оперативу.Помгите!

Tags: jetbrains

> Всем привет.Скачал webstorm а он жрет оперативу сколько не поставь.Idea столько не ест,как шторм.В чем проблема?

Comment: А можно чуть конкретнее про _"жрет оперативу сколько не поставь"_. Может, значения вполне допустимые?

Comment: Просто не используй webstorm.

Comment: Сначала думал ,что 1024 ему мало.Поставил 2. Потом 4.Жрет все)))

Comment: Я не знаю что это но я удалил файл логов под название java_error_in_webstrom HPROF размером 1.5гига)))

Comment: а что значит "жрет оперативу"? Падает с  outOfMemory? Или просто вы в task manager на цифры смотрите? Если второе, то увеличивать xmx точно не стоит, лучше вернуть значение по умолчанию. если первое - надо собрать memory snapshots (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems) и отправить в саппорт

Comment: @lena ни один продукт так не лагает. Жрет ЦП на 50% и сколько ему не дай heapsize все равно ее жрет.Я удалил и скачал vscode.Доволен.Нагрузки вообще никакой нет и кодить приятно

Comment: так ЦП или RAM? немного разные вещи все же

Comment: @lena и то и другое.Я уж и скачал последнюю версию.Тоже самое . Индикатор памяти полный ,кулера орать начинают...